# Creating a clickable android Layout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a relative layout that contains two fragments. My java code is designed to decide which fragment to choose based on the orientation of the screen. I want to have the app switch to a new activity when the screen is touched but I can't figure out how to code it up. I tried setting the main activity xml to be clickable and setting up the intent there but it's not working. I also tried allowing the fragment xml's to be clickable but I can't set an intent with the the fragment java file. My main activity looks like this if anyone can help.

```
    public class StartPage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout useMe;

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Configuration configInfo = getResources().getConfiguration();

        if (configInfo.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            StartPageLandscapeFragment startPageLandscapeFragment = new StartPageLandscapeFragment();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, startPageLandscapeFragment);

            useMe = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.startpage_landscape_layout);

        } else {

            StartPagePortraitFragment startPagePortraitFragment = new StartPagePortraitFragment();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, startPagePortraitFragment);

            useMe = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.startpage_portrait_layout);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        useMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartPage.this, Question1.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to set useMe.setOnClickLIstener(new OnClickListener{

and in onClick method send your's intent

Comment: @StanislavBondar no luck. I get this error that I've been getting "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 0):

you need to `setContentView(R.layout.your's layout);` for this activity

Comment: You must setContentView after super() in onCreate and choose layout where yours relative layout is

Comment: so what is exception you get?

Comment: It had to deal with the inflation of the fragments. So I think it's my layout design causing the error so I'm go to go back and fix it now and post my results in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly you set the onClickListener for your RelativeLayout? You need something like

```
useMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickeListener())
```

Comment: I did that and still no lick

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation i found out I was using fragments in a weird way. I was using fragments to determine layouts dependent on orientation without knowing I could use a seperate layout folder all together to do that. I removed all the fragment work and now everything is good.